# Udyoga Parva - Mahabharata BORI edition with the footnotes

Tags: mahabharata, resource, critical-edition

I am looking for the BORI critical edition of the Mahabharata in Sanskrit, *with footnotes*, so that I can see the different variations available for a text. I saw archive.org has a few of those pdfs. I am specifically looking for Udyoga parva (Volume 6). A pdf I found on archive.org has poorly scanned pages of Udyoga parva. Can you please point me to where can I get Udyoga parva of the Mahabharata (BORI edition)?

Comment: [This copy](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.327547/page/n63) looks decent enough for a scanned book. If you need the original, you can contact BORI directly [here](http://www.bori.ac.in/contact.html). But to read the footnotes, a scanned copy is better because you can zoom in.

Comment: That's the copy I got. I am trying to look for footnotes to verse 5.140.18. The footnotes for that verse are unclear in this scan.

Comment: Agree, [notes](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.327547#page/n567/mode/2up) are not clear for that verse. Bibek Debroy translates it as: "It will be the new moon seven days from now. Let the fight begin on that day, because that is said to be Shakra's day."

Comment: Why don't you buy from a book website?

Comment: I would happily buy an ebook. I don't have the patience to get the book shipped here to US.